# Where is the network message log tab in QGIS on Windows7?

Tags: qgis, windows-7

I want to find out what web requests is QGIS exactly sending to my web server when it connects to a WMS and WFS layer.

In my Linux installation of QGIS 2.0 I can see three tabs in the Log Messages window: General, Plugins, Network.
In my Windows installation of QGIS 2.0 I can only see two tabs in the Log Messages window: General, Plugins.

How do I activate the "Network" log messages tab in QGIS 2.0 on Windows 7?

Comment: I found a partial solution to my problem. After I add a WFS layer, I can click `Layer - Properties - Metadata` and the `Source for this layer` shows the URL of the `GetFeature` network web request. However, QGIS is also sending some other requests like `DescribeFeatureType` and I can't see them anywhere. That's why I still need to show the network message log tab.